# In Java, need to make variables available to Control Break solution

Tags: java, global-variables

Below is an attempt to create a reusable solution for the control break pattern.  It is built on Command Pattern (Action and Test interfaces).  However, I realized my old COBOL thinking got in the way, because this solution is predicated on each of the Action and Test objects having access to "global variables."  And my immediate thought after that was "the need for variable access like this (wider scope) must be an already invented wheel.

How to give all the Actions and Tests below access to a group of variables -- an indeterminate group because this is supposed to be a reusable solution??

```
public class ControlBreak {

public static void controlBreak(Action initialize, 
                                Test   endOfInput, 
                                Test   onChange, 
                                Action breakAction, 
                                Action detailAction, 
                                Action getNext) {

    boolean hasProcessed = false;

    getNext.execute();
    for (initialize.execute();endOfInput.test();detailAction.execute(),getNext.execute()) {
        hasProcessed = true;
        if (onChange.test()) {
            breakAction.execute();
        }
        detailAction.execute();
    }
    if (hasProcessed) {
        breakAction.execute();
    } else {
        // throw empty input exception
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's *really* unclear (to me anywa) what you mean by "the control break" pattern. You haven't described what you're trying to achieve, what `Action` and `Test` are, etc.

Comment: Just pass in a `Map<String, Object> variables` for a straightforward answer. That said, I'd think about whether the set really needs to be indeterminate to allow for reuse. The fact your methods don't really have a well-defined set of inputs and outputs seems like a design smell, not an advantage.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Control Break is -- if not a "design pattern" proper -- a very widely used algorithm.  It hails from ancient batch mainframe data processing terminology.

Comment: @Jon Skeet #2 -  When you have a large set of keyed data, and, for efficiency's sake, you want to read it sequentially and produce another set of data at the aggregate key level, you use control breaking.  For each data item, you do some processing (typically summing totals, or some other aggregation function) -- this is called processing the Detail. Also, you test each key vs. the previous value, and on a change in that value (the Control), you do something (the Break); The input set of data can be file driven, an existing Collection, etc.

Comment: @user1723398: It may be widely used, but if it hails from "ancient" terminology then I'm not surprised it's something I've never heard of. As ever, the more description you can provide within a question, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a few re-reads, it seems like you're trying to abstract a certain control flow, where the parameters can be coupled. In this case, I'd look into generics. I.e. something like this:

```
public static void <TParams> controlBreak(Action<TParams> initialize, ..., TParams params) {
    // ...
    initialize.execute(params)
    // ...
}
```

That way this method will remain reusable, but the various actions / tests can still accept a strongly-typed set of parameters/variables. (The concrete type of `TParam`.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to millimoose, I got where I was going.  Here's the fleshed out code, for reference:

```
    public class ControlBreak<TParams> {

    public TParams controlBreak(Action<TParams> initialize, 
                                    Test<TParams>   endOfInput, 
                                    Test<TParams>   onChange, 
                                    Action<TParams> breakAction, 
                                    Action<TParams> detailAction, 
                                    Action<TParams> getNext,
                                    TParams params) {

        boolean hasProcessed = false;

        getNext.execute(params);
        for (params = initialize.execute(params);endOfInput.test(params);params = detailAction.execute(params),params = getNext.execute(params)) {
            hasProcessed = true;
            if (onChange.test(params)) {
                breakAction.execute(params);
            }
            detailAction.execute(params);
        }
        if (hasProcessed) {
            breakAction.execute(params);
        } else {
            // throw empty input exception
        }
        return params;
    }
}
```